# Where can I find a list of official Windows ME updates (security patches, etc.) that came after the RTM version?

Tags: windows-me

I am using the Windows ME final version (4.90.3000, German; newer installation CDs are not available). I am looking for a chronological list of updates that came after this version, that in the past were possible to install using "Windows Update". Because I want to max out my system and I want to start with a list of all updates.
Where can I find such a list?

It's not that bad if driver updates are not included. But I need at least those for the generic Windows components (which do not depend on hardware). For example security patches for core Windows components.

I only need a list. No update files.

[image: Windows Update]

Comment: What kind of updates have you got in mind?

Comment: @user3840170 I don't understand what is not clear about my question. I simply mean the Windows updates. This cannot be described further.

Comment: To start with, you may add the version you got installed. 'final version' isn't anything helpful.

Comment: @Raffzahn Version added. I want to max out my system. That is my intention and the reason for why I am looking for such a list.

Comment: There was only one version of Millennium, unlike all other major releases of 9x…

Comment: Do updates to bundled software count (e.g. IE6, WMP9), or only bug fixes?

Comment: @user3840170 That's not so important. But I want core components like kernel updates at least. There is an inofficial "Windows ME update CD". But I did not know if it fits for my final version. But now that you say there is only one ME version I think I can use it? https://archive.org/details/wmeupd-r2

Comment: I’d assume the CD contains English versions only, but if you don’t mind mismatched localisation, I guess it should be fine. (Barring things like malware risk, crazy unforeseen incompatibilities, etc.)

Comment: Does Windows ME internal update still work? I'm not on the PC right now to check it...

Comment: I would assume the servers have been decommissioned for a while, so probably not.

Comment: May be interesting for you: https://www.mdgx.com/web.htm#WME